# how to resolve UnsatisfiedDependencyException with spring boot hibernate?

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-boot

I am getting the following issue when Spring boot hibernates Connection.

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'bookController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'bookService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'bookServiceImp': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'bookDao'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'bookDaoImp': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'getSessionFactory' defined in class path resource [com/go/myapp/Config/AppConfig.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow. Please refer the [ask] link for 
more details on how to ask a question and update your question accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

If you are building your project with maven look for the pom file. when you add dependencies there are Compile Dependencies  for those dependencies. For an Example SpringBoot Starter 1.5.8.Release has https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter/1.5.8.RELEASE

SpringBoot 1.5.8.Release 
SpringCore 4.3.12.Release

So please check your dependencies and there compile dependencies . 
posting your POM file would help